# two inline-block elements not being inline, (acting like blocked elements)

Tags: html, css

I've ran into an issue with CSS. I'm trying to have two code blocks (with numbers on the sides) side by side, and after a certain screen size, they'd stack. However, when in a smaller screen size, it does the following.

I'm open to any refactoring, I just need the after media query style to work

[image: error]

Here is my code.

Here is a liveWeave of my code

https://liveweave.com/5s9nqv

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you floating stacked elements? Floats are an outdated pain in the rear technique, and it doesn't seem necessary here anyway.

Comment: Uggh, and you have absolute positioning in there, too. [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), bud. Flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a crack at converting to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It probably needs some fine-tuning.

```css
body {
  background: #24292e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #1f252a;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #404c58;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.code-box {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  margin-top: -7px!important;
  color: #b0b7be;
}

.code-lines {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  overflow: inherit;
}


/* Put media query here */

@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="code-box">
    <div class="code-lines">1 <br>2 <br>3 <br>4 <br>5 <br>6 <br>7 <br>8 <br>9 <br>10 <br>11 <br>12 <br>13 <br>14 <br>15 <br>16 <br>17 <br>18 <br>19 <br>20 <br></div>
    <pre class="box hljs"><code id="submitCode">app.get(['/c/:documentIdOne/:documentIdTwo', '/compare/:documentIdOne/:documentIdTwo'], (req, res) =&gt; {
    const documentOne = req.params.documentIdOne;
    const documentTwo = req.params.documentIdTwo;
    try {
        fs.readFile(`./pastes/${documentOne}.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, documentOne) =&gt; {
            if (err) return res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'One or more posts are not found!' });
            fs.readFile(`./pastes/${documentTwo}.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, documentTwo) =&gt; {
                if (err) return res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'One or more posts are not found!' });
                if (documentTwo &amp;&amp; documentOne) {
                    console.log(documentTwo);
                    console.log(documentOne);
                    res.render('compare.ejs', { documentOne: documentOne, documentTwo: documentTwo })
                }
            })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'An error occured!' });
    }
})</code></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="code-box">
    <div class="code-lines">1 <br>2 <br>3 <br>4 <br>5 <br>6 <br>7 <br>8 <br>9 <br>10 <br>11 <br>12 <br>13 <br>14 <br>15 <br>16 <br>17 <br>18 <br>19 <br>20 <br></div>
    <pre class="box hljs"><code id="submitCode">app.get(['/c/:documentIdOne/:documentIdTwo', '/compare/:documentIdOne/:documentIdTwo'], (req, res) =&gt; {
    const documentOne = req.params.documentIdOne;
    const documentTwo = req.params.documentIdTwo;
    try {
        fs.readFile(`./pastes/${documentOne}.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, documentOne) =&gt; {
            if (err) return res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'One or more posts are not found!' });
            fs.readFile(`./pastes/${documentTwo}.txt`, 'utf-8', (err, documentTwo) =&gt; {
                if (err) return res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'One or more posts are not found!' });
                if (documentTwo &amp;&amp; documentOne) {
                    console.log(documentTwo);
                    console.log(documentOne);
                    res.render('compare.ejs', { documentOne: documentOne, documentTwo: documentTwo })
                }
            })
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.render('error.ejs', { error: 'An error occured!' });
    }
})</code></pre>
  </div>
</main>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/dbomw8g5/)